# Query with SUM using SubSonic

Tags: c#, subsonic, sum

I'm new to Subsonic, I want to ask how to query with SUM?

I know how to query for where condition such as below:

```
Query qryCurOpcode = Station.CreateQuery()
    .WHERE("PRODLINE=PIECERATE_prodline")
    .AND("STATIONID=STNID")
    .AND("SHIFT=PIECERATE_shift");

IDataReader rdrCurOpcode = qryCurOpcode.ExecuteReader();

while (rdrCurOpcode.Read())
{
    PIECERATE_CurOpcode = rdrCurOpcode[Station.Columns.Curopcode].ToString();
}
```

but how to how to query with SUM?

Thanks!
Halim

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
int sum = (int)new Query("Station").GetSum("Shift");
```

You can get more examples from:
[SubSonic Aggregate Queries](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Simple_Aggregate_Queries)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use an aggregate such as sum then the best way is to use Subsonic's aggregates :).  For a whole list of examples check out [SubSonicProject](http://subsonicproject.com/querying/aggregate-queries/)

Here are some examples taken straight from the link above.

```
 double result = new
    Select(Aggregate.Avg("UnitPrice"))
    .From(Product.Schema)
    .ExecuteScalar<double>();

 IDataReader reader = new
    Select(Aggregate.GroupBy("ProductID"), Aggregate.Avg("UnitPrice"))
    .From("Order Details")
    .Where(Aggregate.Avg("UnitPrice"))
    .IsGreaterThan(50)
    .ExecuteReader();
```